# How to access nested parameter values in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, configuration, parameters, yaml

I created a parameter in my `parameters.yml` file:

```
parameters:
    category:
        var: test
```

How can I access this parameter in my `config.yml`? For example, I want to pass this parameter to all my twig files as a global twig variable:

```
twig:
    globals:
        my_var: %category.var% # throws ParameterNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In all the symfony config files I've seen, the entries under 'parameters:' have always been fully qualified. I don't fully understand why this is but it may help you to write the entries in your parameters.yml like this:

```
category1.var1: xxx
category1.var2: yyy
category1.var3. zzz

category2.subcategory1.var1: 5
category2.subcategory1.var2: 10
category2.subcategory2.var1: foo
category2.subcategory2.var2: bar
```

... and so on.

## EDIT

I tried pasting the nested parameter from the question into parameters.local.yml in one of my projects and ran a trivial unit test to retrieve that and a fully qualified parameter from the container e.g.

```
$testUserEmail = $container->getParameter('test.user.email');
$this->assertEquals('dahlia.flower@randomtest.com', $testUserEmail);
$testParam = $container->getParameter('category.var');
$this->assertEquals('test', $testParam);
```

The fully qualified parameter was fine, attempting to get the nested parameter resulted in an `InvalidArgumentException`: The parameter `category.var` must be defined. I don't think parameters can be defined with nesting.

Answer (score 9):

```
$this->container->getParameter('category')['var']
```

I have tested that on symfony 2.8 and it worked for me.

Comment: Worked on Symfony 4

Answer (score 6):

**Or you can write simple ParameterBag which can implement nested parameters dynamically (without config values duplicity):**

```
<?php

namespace Your\Namespace;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException;

class ParameterBagNested extends ParameterBag
{

    /**
     * wire $this->set() logic into add() too
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     */
    public function add( array $parameters )
    {
        foreach ( $parameters as $name => $value ) {
            $this->set( $name, $value );
        }
    }

    /**
     * sets all levels of nested array parameters with dot notation
     * - loggly[host: loggly.com] will be translated this way:
     *  - loggly: [host: loggly.com] - standard array parameter will be left as is
     *  - loggly.host: loggly.com - nested variables ar translated so you can access them directly too as parent.variable
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function set( $name, $value )
    {
        if ( $this->has( $name ) ) {
            // this is required because of array values
            // we can have arrays defined there, so we need to remove them first
            // otherwise some subvalues would to remain in the system and as a result, arrays would be merged, not overwriten by set()
            $this->remove( $name );
        }
        $this->setNested( $name, $value );
    }

    /**
     * remove checks even if name is not array
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function remove( $name )
    {
        $value = $this->get( $name );
        if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
            foreach ( $value as $k => $v ) {
                $this->remove( $name . '.' . $k, $v );
            }
        }
        if ( strpos( $name, '.' ) !== FALSE ) {
            $parts = explode( '.', $name );
            $nameTopLevel = reset( $parts );
            array_shift( $parts );
            $topLevelData = $this->removeKeyByAddress( $this->get( $nameTopLevel ), $parts );
            ksort( $topLevelData );
            $this->setNested( $nameTopLevel, $topLevelData );
        }
        parent::remove( $name );
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @param array $addressParts
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function removeKeyByAddress( $data, $addressParts )
    {
        $updatedLevel = & $data;
        $i = 1;
        foreach ( $addressParts as $part ) {
            if ( $i === count( $addressParts ) ) {
                unset( $updatedLevel[$part] );
            } else {
                $updatedLevel = & $updatedLevel[$part];
                $i++;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @see set()
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    private function setNested( $name, $value )
    {
        if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
            foreach ( $value as $k => $v ) {
                $this->setNested( $name . '.' . $k, $v );
            }
        }
        parent::set( $name, $value );
    }

}
```

**phpunit Test:**

```
<?php

namespace Your\Namespace;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Tests\ParameterBag\ParameterBagTest;

/**
 * its essential to use ParameterBagNested as ParameterBag because this way we run even parent class tests upon it
 * parent class is part of Symfony DIC standard test suite and we use it here just for check if our parameter bag is still ok
 */
use SBKS\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagNested as ParameterBag;

/**
 * testing basic and even added ParameterBag functionality
 */
class ParameterBagNestedTest extends ParameterBagTest
{

    public function testConstructorNested()
    {
        $bag = new ParameterBag(
            array(
                'foo' => array( 'foo1' => 'foo' ),
                'bar' => 'bar',
            )
        );
        $this->assertEquals(
             array(
                 'foo.foo1' => 'foo',
                 'foo' => array(
                     'foo1' => 'foo',
                 ),
                 'bar' => 'bar',
             ),
             $bag->all(),
             '__construct() takes an array of parameters as its first argument'
        );
    }

    public function testRemoveNested()
    {
        $bag = new ParameterBag(
            array(
                'foo' => array(
                    'foo1' => array(
                        'foo11' => 'foo',
                        'foo12' => 'foo',
                    ),
                    'foo2' => 'foo',
                ),
                'bar' => 'bar',
            )
        );

        $bag->remove( 'foo.foo1.foo11' );
        $this->assertEquals(
             array(
                 'foo' => array(
                     'foo1' => array(
                         'foo12' => 'foo',
                     ),
                     'foo2' => 'foo',
                 ),
                 'foo.foo1' => array( 'foo12' => 'foo' ),
                 'foo.foo1.foo12' => 'foo',
                 'foo.foo2' => 'foo',
                 'bar' => 'bar',
             ),
             $bag->all(),
             '->remove() removes a parameter'
        );

        $bag->remove( 'foo' );
        $this->assertEquals(
             array(
                 'bar' => 'bar',
             ),
             $bag->all(),
             '->remove() removes a parameter'
        );
    }

    public function testSetNested()
    {
        $bag = new ParameterBag(
            array(
                'foo' => array(
                    'foo1' => array(
                        'foo11' => 'foo',
                        'foo12' => 'foo',
                    ),
                    'foo2' => 'foo',
                ),
            )
        );
        $bag->set( 'foo', 'foo' );
        $this->assertEquals( array( 'foo' => 'foo' ), $bag->all(), '->set() sets the value of a new parameter' );
    }

    public function testHasNested()
    {
        $bag = new ParameterBag(
            array(
                'foo' => array(
                    'foo1' => array(
                        'foo11' => 'foo',
                        'foo12' => 'foo',
                    ),
                    'foo2' => 'foo',
                ),
            )
        );
        $this->assertTrue( $bag->has( 'foo' ), '->has() returns true if a parameter is defined' );
        $this->assertTrue( $bag->has( 'foo.foo1' ), '->has() returns true if a parameter is defined' );
        $this->assertTrue( $bag->has( 'foo.foo1.foo12' ), '->has() returns true if a parameter is defined' );
        $this->assertTrue( $bag->has( 'foo.foo2' ), '->has() returns true if a parameter is defined' );
    }

}
```

Then you can use it by [injecting Parameter bag into ContainerBuilder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html#basic-usage):

```
$parameterBag = new \Your\Namespace\ParameterBagNested();
$container = new ContainerBuilder($parameterBag);
```

Thats all, you can use nested parameter with dot notation now in Symfony DI container.

If you are using [Symfony plugin in phpstorm](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=phpStorm) it will autocomplete your nested attributes with dot notation too.

Comment: I like the easyness of keeping settings in the yaml format. So this would just bloat it up in a way that I want to avoid. But thanks for explaining this way.

Comment: I dont understand. This ParameterBag is just functionality to allow you to use nested configuration in your yaml configurations. Its backward compatible with all your current configurations. Thats all. It does not define php configuration.

Comment: Where exactly should I inject parameter bag to ContainerBuilder? In Extension classes ContainerBuilder already passed to "load" metod,

Comment: It depends on your stack, you have to pass it to ContainerBuilder constructor as you can see in my example.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, but here is a solution that worked for me.

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        my_var: category['var']
```

#### Explanation

When you import your parameters file into your `app/config/config.yml` file, you can automatically access all variables defined in your parameters file.

Keep in mind, when you use the structure:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    category:
        var: test
```

You are defining a parameter called `category` with a value that is in turn itself a key-value pair array that contains `var` as key and `test` as value.

#### Update

In newer versions of symfony (3.4 - 4.2) you can now do the following:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
       custom_categories: '%categories%'
```

By having this parameter set up:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    categories:       
      - category_A
      - category_B
```

Things to note here:
- in parameters.yml categories is an array

so to use it in a twig template, you should be able to do something like:

```
<ul>
{% for category in categories %}
    <li> {{ category }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Another example with objects:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    marketplace:       
        name: 'My Store'
        address: '...'
```

Configuring twig variables:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
       marketplace: '%marketplace%'
```

Using it in twig:

```
...
<p>{{marketplace.name}}</p>
<p>{{marketplace.address}}</p>
...
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you specify the symfony version number (if applicable) since this is possible?

Comment: I couldn't find to much information about since when this is available, but in my case the need came up in a recent project that I'm working with which is set up with the version 3.2.* of symfony, but I've tested the same solution in a old project using the version: 2.4.*, and it is working as well.

So we can conclude that in order to make this work, a project must be set up with the version 2.4.* of symfony.

Comment: I got the literal string category['var'] in the service. Are you sure?. If I use %category['var']% then I get undefined parameter. I'm using Symfony 3.4

Comment: I'm in the same boat. The value of my_var is the literal string "category['var']" and not the value of category.var. I'm on Symfony 4.1 and a bit flummoxed as to how this might work.

Comment: To access parameters, from a custom service the process is different, first you need to make sure you're importing the service container, and from there you can just do something like this:

$categories = $this->container->getParameter('category');
echo $categories['var'];

output: test.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: @Gustavo Iglesias: This is not about a custom service. Your example is about a Twig global variable. And just like JorgeeFG and Charlie Hills I get the literal string `category['var']`. I'm using Symfony 3.4. Are you sure your example is correct?

Comment: Thanks for updating, but now it doesn't answer the original question anymore. If you look at the original question: how to parse `category.var` as a Twig global variable, without having to parse the entire `category` array?

Answer (score 5):

Symfony's [expression language](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html) syntax to the rescue!  Give this a shot:

```yaml
twig:
    globals:
        my_var: '@=parameter("category")["var"]'
```

Comment: The downside to this solution is that a missing parameter will not be detected during SF container build but only later on, during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

To provide an alternative approach that doesn't require removing values from the setter, I override the getter method instead.

```
namespace NameSpaceFor\ParameterBags;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag;


class ParameterBagParser extends ParameterBag
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function get($name, $parent = null)
    {
        if (null === $parent) {
            $parent = $this->parameters;
        }
        $name = strtolower($name);
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $parent)) {
            if (!$name) {
                throw new ParameterNotFoundException($name);
            }
            if (false !== strpos($name, '.')) {
                $parts = explode('.', $name);
                $key = array_shift($parts);
                if (isset($parent[$key])) {
                    return $this->get(implode('.', $parts), $parent[$key]);
                }
            }
            $alternatives = [];
            foreach ($parent as $key => $parameterValue) {
                $lev = levenshtein($name, $key);
                if ($lev <= strlen($name) / 3 || false !== strpos($key, $name)) {
                    $alternatives[] = $key;
                }
            }
            throw new ParameterNotFoundException($name, null, null, null, $alternatives);
        }

        return $parent[$name];
    }

}
```

It recursively traverses through the name until it is all of the dot notations have been checked.

So it will work with arrays and scalar values.

config.yml:

```
parameters:
   my_param:
     - test

   my_inherited: '%my_param.0%' #test
```

ContainerAware:

```
$container->getParameter('my_param')[0]; //test
```

Comment: Did you edit `ParameterBagParser` in vendor? It looks like that and it is not the best idea. Can your solution be rewritten so that you rewrite `ParameterBagParser` somewhere in the `AppBundle` and let the symfony know about this?

Comment: `ParameterBagParser` is not a default Symfony component. `ParameterBagParser` extends `ParameterBag`, The `ParameterBagParser` would be put anywhere you want in your application code. You could then override `AppKernel::getContainerBuilder` to use the custom `ParameterBagParser` or used as [explained in the answer by palmic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22438205/1144627)

Answer (score -1):

Trick to emulate nested parameters, acccess in the yaml file:

```
parameters:
  crawler:
    urls:
      a: '%crawler.urls.a%'   # here the root of the rest of the tree/array
  crawler.urls.a:
    cat1:
      - aa
      - bb
    cat2:
      - cc

services:
  xx:
    class:  myclass
    arguments:
      $urls:   '%crawler.urls.a%'
```

In Symfony I now access the parameter('crawler') as complete tree, in service xx the subtree/array is accessible.