# Symfony2 read parameters

Tags: symfony, yaml

I could not find an answer to my question. I want to get an paramter using a container. I do this like that:

```
$this->container->getParameter('someParam');
```

Now I want to have some parameters grouped withing a "namespace" like that:

```
system:
    CPU: "i7"
    ram: "8gb"
```

Now I cannot use `$this->container->getParameter('system.CPU');` cause it will scream that "system.CPU" parameter is not set.

Any idea how to read nested parameters from controller?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839157/how-to-access-nested-parameter-values-in-symfony2

Answer (score 3):

In case of nested parameters you should treat this as an array. So in your case you should read:

```
$this->container->getParameter('system');
```

and what you get from it is an array:

```
array('CPU' => 'i7', 'ram' => '8gb')
```

Answer (score 2):

The call of `$this->container->getParameter('system')` will return an

`array('CPU' => 'i7', 'ram' => '8gb')` so you can use them easily as arrays.