# symfony accessing array parameters from parameters.yml in services.yml

Tags: symfony

I got my `parameters.yml` which looks like the following:

```
parameters
    ldap:
        host: 192.168.0.1
        port: 389
```

and my services.yml which looks like this:

```
ldap:
        class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
        factory: [ 'Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap', 'create']
        arguments:
            - ext_ldap
            - host: '%ldap%' # need to pass nested param here (from array)
            - debug: true
```

Here in arguments section in `host` param previously I had a plain string passed from `parameters.yml`. Now `host` param in `parameters.yml` was moved 1 level lower and I need to get it from there and pass to `services.yml`. I tried something like this:

```
'%ldap%['host']'
```

or

```
'ldap.host'
```

or

```
'ldap['host']'
```

nut none of them worked. Is there some way to access array params passed from `parameters.yml` in `services.yml`.

Comment: issue solved with the help of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839157/how-to-access-nested-parameter-values-in-symfony2) post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access nested parameter values in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839157/how-to-access-nested-parameter-values-in-symfony2)