# Symfony 4.4 configuration yaml in tabbed format

Tags: symfony, configuration, yaml

In former versions of Symfony, I could set my configuration like this in `parameters.yml`:

```
app:
    group1:
        param1: 'myvalue'
```

And read its value with `$this->getParameter('app.group1.param1')`.

In **Symfony 4.4** this format seems to be not working, and I'm forced to do this in my `services.yml` file:

```
app.group1.param1
```

The docs only refer to this format and doing otherwise throws an error.

Can I use the old tabbed format somehow?

Comment: Are you using actual tabs or spaces.

Comment: Not real tabs, 4 spaces

Comment: And you are positive that app.group1.param1 worked without a bundle's extension processing it?  I don't have an old Symfony version to test against but app would be defined as an array parameter with another array called group1.  Don't recall it behaving differently.  In many cases you would use a bit of code to define a new parameter using the dot format.

Comment: I don't think I used any extension, it was my normal way to work in all my former projects

Comment: there is a semantic difference, when assuming "app.group1.param" to be the key of a value versus assuming that everything is basically a deeply nested array/object which you access with the dot-syntax (like with the property accessor). maybe there once upon a time was a compiler pass that did this? however, I can't find any indication so far ... perhaps the `app` key was special once ... perhaps it works with very specific root-level keys, that expose this to the container ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22438205/4275413 suggests, that your wish isn't quite new and suggests injecting a specific parameter bag just for this ;o)

Comment: Ok, thank you. So I've been doing _wrong_ all my life XD