# Symfony2: how to read parameters array in config.yml

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

my parameters.yml file has:

```
parameters:
     title:
          subtitle: value
```

i want to pass the `value` to a service in config.yml

```
my_service:
        class: the_class
        arguments: [ %title.subtitle%] //didn't work
        arguments: [ %title['subtitle']%] //didn't work
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried to define title as an hashmap like `title: {value:'someValue', subtitle:'another value'}` ? By the way, parameter references have to be quoted. `arguments: ['%title%']` [see documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html#parameters-in-configuration-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2: Reference string or an array in config yaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360754/symfony2-reference-string-or-an-array-in-config-yaml)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `%` notation doesn't work but it can be accomplished the following way:

```
my_service:
    class: the_class
    arguments: ["@=container.getParameter('title')['subtitle']"]
```

It works at least for symfony 2.7.3

More info about the expression language can be found in the cookbook:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language

Comment: Where did you find this syntax `"@=container.getParameter('title')['subtitle']"`?

Comment: check the doc https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/service_container/expression_language.html

Answer (score 16):

Symfony2 doesn't support reading individual elements on a parameter array using the `%` notation. What you are doing is not possible out of the box.

The only way to do that would be to create your own `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag` which would support fetching an array item.