# how to use a parameter inside of another parameter in YAML

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml

So I need to append a parameter inside of another parameter.
like this (this actually works)

```
parameters:
    locationMenuTop: 21142
cjwsiteaccess.textilenetwork_de.parameters:
    locationMenuTop: %locationMenuTop%
```

but as soon as try to go one step deeper.

```
parameters:
    nodeSettings: 
         locationMenuTop: 21142
cjwsiteaccess.textilenetwork_de.parameters:
    locationMenuTop: %nodeSettings.locationMenuTop%
```

It throws this error

[image]

Comment: You can't use a multidimensional array as `%array.key%`. Look at this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919679/symfony2-how-to-read-parameters-array-in-config-yml

Comment: That question is refering to concatenating parameters when using Dependency injection

Comment: It's why I don't flag it as dupicate. The problem is the same. You cannot retrieve a param that is a key of an array by doing `%array.key%` , and this everywhere, not only in service declaration. Also, the answers given should help. You can define your param as `nodeSettings.locationMenuTop: 21142` and do the same for every parameter of `nodeSettings`. Or write your own `ParameterBag`

Comment: can't write my own parameter bag, I'm using this code for a huge company that doesn't give me much flexibility, since 15 different sites are running on the same code. However you can post the comment above as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define your parameters as array, you can't retrieve them by "path" (i.e. `%array.key%`).

A workaround :

```
parameters:
    nodeSettings.locationMenuTop: 21142
    nodeSettings.locationMenuBottom: ...
    # And so on
cjwsiteaccess.textilenetwork_de.parameters:
    locationMenuTop: %nodeSettings.locationMenuTop%
```